# How to install PyTables 2.3.1 with Anaconda, missing HDF5 library

Tags: python, pip, hdf5, pytables, conda

I need to run an older verion of PyTables, that is 2.3.1, in and Anaconda environment on **Linux**. But I cannot install it.

```
conda install -n myenv pytables=2.3.1
```

fails finding the appropriate version.

```
conda install -n myenv pytables=2
```

installs PyTables 2.4.0 successfully. But I need 2.3.1.

Also activating the environment and installing via pip does not work.

```
pip install tables==2.3.1
```

fails with the following error:

> .. ERROR:: Could not find a local HDF5 installation.
>
> You may need to explicitly state where your local HDF5 headers and
>
> library can be found by setting the `HDF5_DIR` environment
>
> variable or by using the `--hdf5` command-line option.

Where can I find the HDF5 installation of Anaconda? And how do I pass the `--hdf5` option to pip? I already tried

```
pip install tables==2.3.1 --install-option="--hdf5=/home/me/Programme/anaconda"
```

But it also fails with the same error as above.

Comment: Did you `conda install -n myenv hdf5`?

Comment: Yes, but the dependency is already satisfied, i.e. HDF5 is already available in the environment. Otherwise the installation of PyTables 2.4 would also fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
env HDF5_DIR="/home/me/Programme/anaconda" pip install tables==2.3.1
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to install a completely different package with pip on a new conda environment when I got the same error.

```
 conda install -c conda-forge pytables
```

This helped me to get rid of the error and successfully install the package.